# Changing value of textarea using onclick function

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript. I can not change value of textarea when I press Goodbye button. But When I click hello it is  working fine! Can you help to change the value of textarea when it is pressed  the second time.

```
Comment:<br>
<textarea id="myTextarea">
</textarea><br>

<input id="text" type="text" value="Hello" name="text"><br>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">hello</button><br>
<input id="text" type="text" value="Goodbye" name="text"><br>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Gooodbye</button>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    
    var text =document.getElementById("text").value;
    document.getElementById("myTextarea").value=text;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I would recommend to learn JavaScript. There is a good book: https://javascript.info/

Comment: You cannot use the same ID multiple times in HTML. `document.getElementById("text").value;` will always select the first one found.

Comment: You cannot use 2 elements with the same id. Id must be unique and can only be used once.

Comment: @Naida I am actually learning it

Answer (score 1):

Your `goodbye` and `hello` input fields has the same `id` - that when call your `myFunction` the `text` variable will always be the value of your first `input`.

You have to use different ids for each `input` the you can handle `click` events separately for each button.

```js
function handleHelloClick() {
  var text = document.getElementById("text-hello").value;
  setTextarea(text);
}

function handleGoodbyeClick() {
  var text = document.getElementById("text-goodbye").value;
  setTextarea(text);
}

function setTextarea(text) {
  document.getElementById("myTextarea").value = text;
}
```

```html
Comment:<br />
<textarea id="myTextarea"></textarea><br />

<input id="text-hello" type="text" value="Hello" name="text" /><br />
<button type="button" onclick="handleHelloClick()">hello</button><br />

<input id="text-goodbye" type="text" value="Goodbye" name="text" /><br />
<button type="button" onclick="handleGoodbyeClick()">Gooodbye</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two elements with the same ID. This is why it does not work.

You will want something like this;

```
Comment:<br>
<textarea id="myTextarea">
</textarea><br>

<input id="text" type="text" value="Hello" name="text"><br>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">hello</button><br>
<input id="text2" type="text" value="Goodbye" name="text"><br>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction2()">Gooodbye</button>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    
    var text =document.getElementById("text").value;
    document.getElementById("myTextarea").value=text;

}
function myFunction2() {
    
    var text =document.getElementById("text2").value;
    document.getElementById("myTextarea").value=text;

}
</script>
```

Comment: I understant. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should have different id's for different inputs.
It's a bad practice to have same ID for all the elements.

```
<textarea id="myTextarea">
</textarea><br>

<input id="hello-input" type="text" value="Hello" name="text"><br>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction('hello-input')">hello</button><br>
<input id="bye-input" type="text" value="Goodbye" name="text"><br>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction('bye-input')">Gooodbye</button>


<script>
function myFunction(inputId) {
    
    var text =document.getElementById(inputId).value;
    document.getElementById("myTextarea").value=text;
}
</script>
```

You can start from learning JavaScript: https://javascript.info/

Answer (score 0):

Two inputs with the same id is not a correct HTML, ids should be uniques on a page.
Try this:

```
<textarea id="myTextarea">
</textarea><br>

<input id="text1" type="text" value="Hello" name="text"><br>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction('text1')">hello</button><br>
<input id="text2" type="text" value="Goodbye" name="text"><br>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction('text2')">Gooodbye</button>


<script>
function myFunction(inputId) {
    
    var text = document.getElementById(inputId).value;
    document.getElementById("myTextarea").value=text;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript when you assign the same ID to two different elements and then try to fetch an element using `document.getElementById()` it will fetch only the first element that matches the ID name.

So, you can probably assign a different ID to the goodbye element. Also, you can have different functions to handle two different button clicks.

Please check out the example below.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("text"));
```

```html
Comment:<br>
<textarea id="myTextarea">
</textarea><br>

<input id="hello" type="text" value="Hello" name="text"><br>
<button type="button" onclick="hello()">hello</button><br>
<input id="goodbye" type="text" value="Goodbye" name="text"><br>
<button type="button" onclick="goodbye()">Gooodbye</button>


<script>
function hello() {  
    var text =document.getElementById("hello").value;
    document.getElementById("myTextarea").value=text;
}

function goodbye() {
    var text =document.getElementById("goodbye").value;
    document.getElementById("myTextarea").value=text;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's never a good idea to use an id twice. If you call document.getElementById("some-id") the browser will return the first element it finds. So the browser will never return the goodbye button.

```js
function myHelloFunction() {
    var text =document.getElementById("hello-button").value;
    document.getElementById("myTextarea").value=text;
};
  function myGoodbyeFunction() {
    var text =document.getElementById("goodbye-button").value;
    document.getElementById("myTextarea").value=text;
}
```

```html
<br>
<textarea id="myTextarea">
</textarea><br>

<input id="hello-button" type="text" value="Hello" name="text"><br>
<button type="button" onclick="myHelloFunction()">hello</button><br>
<input id="goodbye-button" type="text" value="Goodbye" name="text"><br>
<button type="button" onclick="myGoodbyeFunction()">Gooodbye</button>
```

Comment: To read more about [why duplicate ids are not allowed in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240240/why-are-duplicate-ids-not-allowed-in-html/48240438#48240438) or take a look at the documentation from [moz://a](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)