# how to create iframe inside multiple tags using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Here I want to insert iframe inside ins tag using JavaScript... here is the code that I am trying but its creating two iframes in side single ins tag....
here is the ins

```html
<ins class="e120x600" id="120x600"></ins>
<ins class="e120x600" id="120x600"></ins>
```

Here is the JavaScript

```html
<script>
  elem = document.querySelectorAll('.e120x600');
  for (let i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    var size = elem[i].id
    var str = size.substring(size.indexOf("x") + 1);
    var H = str.replace('x', '');
    var str = size.substring(0, size.indexOf('x'));
    var W = str.replace('x', '');

    var e = document.createElement('iframe');
    elem[i].appendChild(e);
    g = e.style;
    e.scrolling = "no";
    e.frameBorder = 0;
    e.id = "ifrm";
    e.allow = "autoplay";
    e.id = "ifrm";
    e.width = W;
    e.height = H;
    g.border = 0;
    g.overflow = "hidden";

  }
</script>
```

Comment: You got 2 elements with same id `id="120x600"`

Comment: yes all ids and classes are same

Comment: It is not allowed.

Comment: see this for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240240/why-are-duplicate-ids-not-allowed-in-html

Comment: i would avoid to assign the same id attribute to more than one iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got 2 elements with same id `id="120x600"`, following that I've changed this

```
var size = elem[i].id
```

To this:

```
var size = elem[i].className.replace("e", "");
```

And now it seems to be working fine.

In the same matter- from fedeghe comment, I've changed this:

```
e.id = "ifrm";
```

To be unique like so:

```
e.id = "ifrm" + i;
```

```js
elem = document.querySelectorAll('.e120x600');
for (let i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    var size = elem[i].className.replace("e", "");
    var str = size.substring(size.indexOf("x") + 1);
    var H=  str .replace('x','');
    var str = size.substring(0, size.indexOf('x'));
    var W=  str .replace('x','');

    var e = document.createElement('iframe');
    elem[i].appendChild(e);
                    g = e.style;
                    e.scrolling = "no";
                    e.frameBorder = 0;
                    e.id = "ifrm";
                    e.allow = "autoplay";
                    e.id = "ifrm" + i;
                    e.width = W;
                    e.height = H;
                    g.border = 0;
                    g.overflow = "hidden";

}
```

```css
iframe{
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<ins class="e120x600" id="120x601"></ins>
<ins class="e120x600" id="120x602"></ins>
```

Comment: even here
i would avoid to assign the same id attribute to more than one iframe

Comment: okay now here is the tricky part if the javascript is called from an url like<ins class="e120x600" id="120x601"></ins> <script async src="//localhost/js/js.js"></script>.......<ins class="e120x600" id="120x602"></ins><script async src="//localhost/js/js.js"></script> it will create 2 iframe with in the tag,in total four iframe..how to fix that..?