# How to make this code work with .each function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, elementor

I have the following piece of code in a script tag that I need to get working for all #tel ID elements on the page. I can only get it to work for the first #tel element. I've been trying to use .each function - but no luck...

The reason being is that I can't seem to get the ACF repeater URL to suit my needs here. The Advanced section of the dynamic content link part is not displaying. So I am trying to make a hack in an HTML widget for this.
But I need it to work for all buttons with button ID #tel.

Here's the code:

```js
var link = document.getElementById('tel');
var href = link.getAttribute('href');

link.setAttribute('href', href.replace('http://', 'tel:'));
```

```html
<div class="elementor-button-wrapper">
    <a href="http://44400907" class="elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-xs" role="button" id="tel">
        <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper">
            <span class="elementor-button-text elementor-inline-editing" data-elementor-setting-key="text" data-elementor-inline-editing-toolbar="none">
                44 40 09 07
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: IDs are unique. There can only be one element with one ID. Use classes or data attributes.

Comment: FYI: [Why are duplicate ids not allowed in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240240/why-are-duplicate-ids-not-allowed-in-html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML/javascript element IDs must be unique. So in your case you can use class for that:

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.tel');
for(let i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
{
  let link = links[i];
  var href = link.getAttribute('href');

  link.setAttribute('href', href.replace('http://', 'tel:'));
}
```

```html
<div class="elementor-button-wrapper">
            <a href="http://44400907" class="elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-xs tel" role="button">
                        <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper">
                        <span class="elementor-button-text elementor-inline-editing" data-elementor-setting-key="text" data-elementor-inline-editing-toolbar="none">44 40 09 07</span>
                </span>
            </a>
    </div>
    
<div class="elementor-button-wrapper">
            <a href="http://44400908" class="elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-xs tel" role="button">
                        <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper">
                        <span class="elementor-button-text elementor-inline-editing" data-elementor-setting-key="text" data-elementor-inline-editing-toolbar="none">44 40 09 08</span>
                </span>
            </a>
    </div>

<div class="elementor-button-wrapper">
            <a href="http://44400909" class="elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-xs tel" role="button">
                        <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper">
                        <span class="elementor-button-text elementor-inline-editing" data-elementor-setting-key="text" data-elementor-inline-editing-toolbar="none">44 40 09 09</span>
                </span>
            </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Dohh! - Sometimes you are just so focused on the goal :/ that you can't see the issue. Thx for the reminder. 

The anchor is now a child of the class '.tel' the 'var links = document.querySelectorAll('.tel');' should be '.tel a', right?

Comment: So if I also want to remove blank spaces from the URLs. How can I add this to the same script?

Comment: Yes, `.tel a` is correct. I assume only numbers allowed, in that case a simple regex will do: `href.replace('http://', 'tel:').replace(/[^\d]/g, '')`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very helpful. I ended up changing the class to a custom data type. Since I can control that directly on the link itself.

Thank you for all you help.