# I can't get the JavaScript toggle to work

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle

What I want to do is when I click the task it will have a line through the text means that I'm done with the task. but the add event listener function for this is not working,  I'm working with the javascript toggle and that's all I can think of right now to achieve this functionality.

Is there another way to do this? I searched on the internet and it seems complicated when I'm trying to figure it out.

```js
const addBtn = document.querySelector("#push");
const taskInput = document.querySelector("#taskInput");
const taskOutput = document.querySelector("#tasks");

addBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let newTasks = taskInput.value;
  if (newTasks.length == 0) {
    alert("Please enter a task");
  } else {
    taskOutput.innerHTML += `<div class="task">
                <span id="taskname">${newTasks} </span>
                <button class="delete" id="deleteButton"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i> </button>
    
    
            </div>
            `;
    //delete
    let deleteBtn = document.querySelector("#deleteButton");
    deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.parentNode.remove();
    });
    //line through
    let theTask = document.querySelectorAll(".task");
    theTask.addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.classList.toggle("completed");
    });
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(241, 206, 221, 1) 0%, rgba(124, 184, 254, 1) 100%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid white;
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 450px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 30px 40px;
}

#new-task {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

#new-task input {
  width: 70%;
  height: 45px;
  font-family: 'Manrope', sans-seif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border: 2px solid #d1d3d4;
  padding: 12px;
  color: #111111;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#new-task input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: violet;
}

#new-task button {
  font-family: 'Manrope', sans-seif;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  background-color: violet;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#tasks {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.task {
  background-color: white;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-bottom: 2px solid violet;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.task span {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.task button {
  background-color: violet;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.task button:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.completed {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="new-task">
      <input type="text" name="" id="taskInput" placeholder="Task to be done" />
      <button id="push">ADD</button>
    </div>


    <div id="tasks"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Every time you do `taskOutput.innerHTML += ...`, you're re-creating all the elements in `taskOutput`, but never re-attach the events to the newly-created elements. See how to [delegate events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation) to prevent loss of the event listeners. Notice also, that `id`s must be unique within the document. And more, take a look what [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns, you're trying to attach a listener to NodeList.

Answer (score 0):

`theTask` is a list of nodes. Trying to attach event listener on this list is causing issues.

Also, you will be inserting lots of buttons with same id `deleteButton` and spans with same id `taskname` which is incorrect and can cause undefined behavior.

For `theTask` fix, you may want to do something like:

```
let theTasks = [...document.querySelectorAll(".task")];
theTasks.forEach(task => {
  task.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("completed");
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

querySelectorAll will return the list of nodes matching the selector **tasks**. So you have to iterate through each of those nodes and add your listener. See the below code snippet

```
let theTasks = document.querySelectorAll(".task");
theTasks.forEach((task) => {
  task.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("completed");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `innerHTML` to create manipulate the DOM for an application like a todo list is probably not a good idea. The answers to [Advantages of createElement over innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2946656/18595321) give good explanations why.

It is worth noting that in the `innerHTML` code, the `span` and the `button` are created with an `id` and so all of these elements will have the same `id`. It is also probably not a good idea to have duplicate `ids` on one page. [Why are duplicate ID values not allowed in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48240240/18595321) explains why.

Also, adding event listeners to every new task is also probably not a good idea. [What is DOM Event delegation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1687296/18595321) gives a good explanation why.

Finally, the [Difference between HTMLCollection, NodeLists, and arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763358/difference-between-htmlcollection-nodelists-and-arrays-of-objects) and [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) explain how to get lists of elements that can be manipulated.

So, I have rewritten the task creation code in the `addBtn.addEventListener` to show one way how this could be done with `document.createElement()`.

And I have created a separate event listener on the Tasks container `div`, which handles both task deletion and task completion.

I also added the following CSS so that clicking on a trash can icon is handled by the parent button. Without this CSS, clicking on an icon would not delete the task.

```css
div#tasks i {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

To make the todo list more visible in the code snippet below, I reduced the `heights`, `margins`, and `paddings` of some of the elements in the CSS.

I also added a link to the font awesome icon library.

```js
const addBtn = document.querySelector("#push");
const taskInput = document.querySelector("#taskInput");
const taskOutput = document.querySelector("#tasks");

taskOutput.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (event.target && event.target.nodeName === "SPAN") {
    event.target.classList.toggle("completed");
  }
  if (event.target && event.target.nodeName === "BUTTON") {
    event.target.parentNode.remove();
  }
});

addBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let newTasks = taskInput.value;
  if (newTasks.length == 0) {
    alert("Please enter a task");
  } else {
    //  Create a task DIV
    const newTaskElement = document.createElement("div");
    newTaskElement.classList.add("task");

    //  Create a SPAN with the task name 
    const newTaskNameElement = document.createElement("span");
    const taskTextnode = document.createTextNode(newTasks);
    newTaskNameElement.appendChild(taskTextnode);

    //  Create a BUTTON with a TRASH CAN ICON 
    const newTaskDeleteButton = document.createElement("button");
    const deleteImageElement = document.createElement("i");
    deleteImageElement.classList.add("fa-solid", "fa-trash");
    newTaskDeleteButton.appendChild(deleteImageElement);

    //  Append the SPAN and the BUTTON to the task DIV
    newTaskElement.appendChild(newTaskNameElement);
    newTaskElement.appendChild(newTaskDeleteButton);

    //  Append the task DIV to the TASK LIST DIV
    taskOutput.appendChild(newTaskElement);
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(241, 206, 221, 1) 0%, rgba(124, 184, 254, 1) 100%);
  font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
}


/* ADDED TO MAKE SURE THAT THE TRASH ICON DOES NOT PROCESS CLICKS */

div#tasks i {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid white;
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 450px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 3px 4px;
}

#new-task {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 6px 4px;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

#new-task input {
  width: 70%;
  height: 45px;
  font-family: 'Manrope', sans-seif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border: 2px solid #d1d3d4;
  padding: 12px;
  color: #111111;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#new-task input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: violet;
}

#new-task button {
  font-family: 'Manrope', sans-seif;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  background-color: violet;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#tasks {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 6px 4px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.task {
  background-color: white;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-bottom: 2px solid violet;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.task span {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.task button {
  background-color: violet;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.task button:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.completed {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div id="new-task">
    <input type="text" name="" id="taskInput" placeholder="Task to be done" />
    <button id="push">ADD</button>
  </div>
  <div id="tasks"></div>
</div>
```