# Function works only for first element

Tags: javascript

I want to add more "read more" buttons, but every response only for 1st one. Buttons open only first element.
I tried some versions with querySelectorAll but I can't figure that out unfortunately...
How can I resolve this?

```js
function myFunction() {
  const dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  const moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  const btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Przeczytaj więcej";
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Zwiń";
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="quote__box__text">
  lorem ipsum <span id="dots">...</span>
  <span id="more" Lorem ipsum</span>
  <button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>
</div>

<div class="quote__box__text">
  lorem ipsum <span id="dots">...</span>
  <span id="more" Lorem ipsum</span>
  <button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>
</div>
```

Comment: ids should be unique so `getElementById` will only return the first element it finds with that id

Comment: @Pete but it can be done with it as well, not bad just a little more code

Comment: @AfzalK. no, it *is* bad to have non-unique IDs. There are plenty of tools, libraries, or other things that might refuse to work. You'd then need "a little more code" to fix each and probably also to fix other interactions between them. Whereas using unique IDs removes all of this maintenance tax you'd impose otherwise.

Comment: Why are you reinventing the `<details>` element?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are duplicate ID values not allowed in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240240/why-are-duplicate-id-values-not-allowed-in-html)

Comment: @AfzalK. yes if you ignore 80% of what I said *and* ignore wider context *and* take the simplest possible example, your answer works. Lots of conditionals to try and justify "little more code" over "correctness".

Comment: thats not the case, if lets suppose ids should be removed then we can say, call function should be removed as why to include it in all buttons, plus it will be easy for OP if he wants to make some changes, while i myself dont bother to even use classses neither IDs, i prefer css selectors

Comment: while knowing most of what he wants can be achieved with css itself

Comment: @AfzalK. none unique ids are invalid html - try validate it.  You shouldn't do it as it can lead to unknown errors and different browsers treating invalid html in different ways.  You might have found a work around but, but whose to say it will work in future if browsers deicde they will strip out duplicate ids

Comment: i never said it should be, a week ago i was working on a shopify store, pagefly was loading some images, but the location of those images was changed, they were more than 100, so instead of using classes and ids which were not same for all images, i used querySelector targeted the url, and changed the location for all of them, whereas if i had to update the location for them it would take too much time

Comment: it would be easy for him to use class, if its dynamic site, but if its static , he will have to go add classes to all pages

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment, ids should be unique - instead use classes and then you can bind the click to each button and get the elements based on the clicked element

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.myBtn');    // get all buttons

buttons.forEach(button => {                             // loop through the buttons and add an click event listener
  button.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const container = e.currentTarget.closest('.quote__box__text'); // get the container the clicked button is in
    const dots = container.querySelector('.dots');  // get the dots element in the container
    const more = container.querySelector('.more');  // get the more element in the contanier

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {  // do your logic
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    more.style.display = "none";
    e.currentTarget.innerHTML = "Przeczytaj więcej";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    more.style.display = "inline";
    e.currentTarget.innerHTML = "Zwiń";
  }
  });
});
```

```css
.more {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote__box__text">
  lorem ipsum <span class="dots">...</span>
  <span class="more">Lorem ipsum</span>
  <button class="myBtn">Przeczytaj więcej</button>
</div>

<div class="quote__box__text">
  lorem ipsum <span class="dots">...</span>
  <span class="more">
Lorem ipsum</span>
  <button class="myBtn">Przeczytaj więcej</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Also a good approach, and being closer to the original may be more accessible to the OP.

Comment: hmm yeah, it would have been better to use a class to change the shown and hidden elements like your answer and the classlist contains is also nicer than the checking display property

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is invalid, you can't use the same `id` on more than one element. Use a class instead, and hook up the handler dynamically. Then, in the click handler, use the specific button that was clicked to find the elements in that same `div` that you want to change. I also strongly recommend using classes rather than inline styles.

For instance:

```js
function clickHandler(event) {
    // Because we attached this handler to each button directy, the
    // button that was clicked is available as `event.currentTarget`.
    const button = event.currentTarget;
    // Find the containing element with the class `quote__box__text`,
    // then toggle a class on it
    const div = button.closest(".quote__box__text");
    if (!div) {
        return;
    }
    div.classList.toggle("open");
    
    // Update the button text depending on whether the div
    // now has the class or not
    button.textContent = div.classList.contains("open")
        ? "Zwiń"
        : "Przeczytaj więcej";
}
for (const button of document.querySelectorAll(".myBtn")) {
    button.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
}
```

```css
/* Normally, .more elements inside .quote__box__text are hidden */
.quote__box__text .more {
    display: none;
}

/* But they're shown when .quote__box__text has .open */
.quote__box__text.open .more {
    display: inline;
}

/* ...but the .dots elements are hidden */
.quote__box__text.open .dots {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote__box__text">
    lorem ipsum <span class="dots">...</span>
    <span class="more">Lorem ipsum</span>
    <button class="myBtn">Przeczytaj więcej</button>
</div>

<div class="quote__box__text">
    lorem ipsum <span class="dots">...</span>
    <span class="more">Lorem ipsum</span>
    <button class="myBtn">Przeczytaj więcej</button>
</div>
```

In that example, see how the CSS classes and structure drive the hiding and display of the elements.

We could change the button text in a similar way if we want; I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader. :-) (Hint: Use elements inline the `button` you show/hide.)

More to explore:

- [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS)
- [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)
- [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)
- [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Answer (score -1):

some changes made it more flexible, as it don't rely on specific element ids but can instead work with any elements that have the same parent structure.

```js
  
function myFunction(btnText) {
    const parent = btnText.parentNode;
    const dots = parent.querySelector("#dots");
    const moreText = parent.querySelector("#more");
  

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Przeczytaj więcej";
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Zwiń";
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

```css
span#more {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote__box__text">
   Lorem ipsum <span id="dots">...</span>
  <span id="more"> Lorem ipsum</span>
  <button onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn">Read more</button>
</div>

<div class="quote__box__text">
   Lorem ipsum <span id="dots">...</span>
  <span id="more"> Lorem ipsum</span>
  <button onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn">Read more</button>
</div>

<div class="quote__box__text">
   Lorem ipsum <span id="dots">...</span>
  <span id="more"> Lorem ipsum</span>
  <button onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn">Read more</button>
</div>

<div class="quote__box__text">
   Lorem ipsum <span id="dots">...</span>
  <span id="more"> Lorem ipsum</span>
  <button onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn">Read more</button>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!