# Copy Text to Clipboard loop result

Tags: javascript

The HTML code below is a loop result. All I want is to copy the input value by clicking the button, but I can't make it work.

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Get the text field
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");

  // Select the text field
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); // For mobile devices

  // Copy the text inside the text field
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);

  // Alert the copied text
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Hello World" id="myInput">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>

<input type="text" value="Hello World fdasfds" id="myInput">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>

<input type="text" value="Hello World fdasfd fsdafds" id="myInput">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
```

If there is only one entry, it works perfectly.

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Get the text field
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");

  // Select the text field
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); // For mobile devices

  // Copy the text inside the text field
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);

  // Alert the copied text
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Hello World fdasfd fsdafds" id="myInput">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identifier is called an identifier because it identifies one element. If you use it for three elements, only the first ID will take effect, and the browser will ignore the others.

For three input fields, use three different IDs.

#### Example

```js
function myFunction(id) {
  // Get the text field
  var copyText = document.getElementById(id);

  // Select the text field
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); // For mobile devices

  // Copy the text inside the text field
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);

  // Alert the copied text
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Hello World 1st input" id="myInput-1">
<button onclick="myFunction('myInput-1')">Copy text</button>

<input type="text" value="Hello World 2nd input" id="myInput-2">
<button onclick="myFunction('myInput-2')">Copy text</button>

<input type="text" value="Hello World 3rd input" id="myInput-3">
<button onclick="myFunction('myInput-3')">Copy text</button>
```

#### More information

- [`id` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) - MDN Docs
- [Why are duplicate ID values not allowed in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240240/why-are-duplicate-id-values-not-allowed-in-html) - StackOverflow Answer

Comment: Good answer! Different Id helps identify different elements and it is important to use similar elements.

Comment: Your code make alert but doesn't copy value.

Comment: @J.Porter Copying text is a rather cumbersome process in browsers. It doesn't work at all with iframes and the HTTP protocol. The question was not about that, but rather about why the three different input fields don't work: it's because they are called in the same way. You can [read more information here about clipboard copy with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript). Try the code on a live website using the HTTPS protocol, and it will work, just as it already worked for the person asking the question.